# Pandas find and interpolate missing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is pretty much a follow up from [Pandas pivot or reshape dataframe with NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64905007/pandas-pivot-or-reshape-dataframe-with-nan)

When decoding videos some frames go missing and that data needs to be interpolated

Current df

```
frame   pvol    vvol    area    label
0       NaN     109.8   120     v
2       NaN     160.4   140     v
0       23.1    NaN     110     p
1       24.3    NaN     110     p
2       25.6    NaN     112     p
```

Expected df

```
frame   pvol    vvol    p_area  v_area
0       23.1    109.8   110     110
1       24.3    135.1   110     111 # Interpolated for label v
2       25.6    160.4   112     120
```

I know I can do `df.interpolate()` once the `current_df` is reshaped for only p frames. The reshaping is the issue.

Note: `label p >= label v` meaning label `p` will always have all the frames but `v` can have missed frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape, dropna as in the previous question, except that now you need to specify that you want to drop only empty columns, then interpolate:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='frame', columns='label')
         .dropna(axis=1, how='all')            # only drop empty columns
         .interpolate()                        # interpolate
      )

out.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
       p_pvol  v_vvol  p_area  v_area
frame                                
0        23.1   109.8   110.0   120.0
1        24.3   135.1   110.0   130.0
2        25.6   160.4   112.0   140.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `dropna` remove the issue

```
s = df.set_index(['frame','label']).unstack().dropna(thresh=1,axis=1)
s.columns = s.columns.map('_'.join)
s = s.interpolate()
Out[279]: 
       pvol_p  vvol_v  area_p  area_v
frame                                
0        23.1   109.8   110.0   120.0
1        24.3   135.1   110.0   130.0
2        25.6   160.4   112.0   140.0
```